# Delete top row of excel file using SSIS

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have an excel file that has a header row which is a row that I want to delete.  The header row in thsi file are the cells of A1 to W1 merged into one.  This causes a problem when I try to read the file because I am expecting column names.  Proper column names exist in the second row of the file, which is why I want to delete the first.

To accomplish this I thought I'd be able to use the 'Excel Source' item in SSIS since it supports a SQL option to write a query.  What I want to do is something like this:

```
SELECT * from ExcelFile WHERE Row > 1
```

My file only has data in columns A thru W.

I don't know what syntax I can use in the query to do this.  The query builder that is in the Excel Source item will allow me to do many things with columns but I don't see an option for doing anything with rows.  Searching online and using the help didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: Take a look here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/947fa27e-e31f-4108-a889-18acebce9217/ssis-excel-import-skip-first-rows?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: This might work, but if I use this I'd want to get the name of the sheet (there is only 1) and the columns of data programatically.  I don't want to have to change my code if the source file changes.  Any suggestions on doing that and using that with what you suggest?

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of #2 in that answer. Using a conditional split to check for the header content, as long as that remained unchanged. However, the answer below also has a good solution given that the first row is always a header.

Answer (score 1):

None of these solutions will work because the Excel driver will be confused by the merged first line. You won't be able to use any driver features such as skip first row to do this. You need to run some script to open the Excel file and delete the row manually.

There is some basic sample script at this site:

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1327014-1292-1.aspx

The code below is adapted from the code written by *snsingh* at that site.

You would obviously want to use connnection manager properties, not hard coded paths

Excel needs to be installed on the SSIS Server for it to work - this is the only way to use Excel automation.

```
Dim filename As String
Dim appExcel As Object
Dim newBook As Object
Dim oSheet1 As Object

appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
filename = "C:\test.xls"
appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False

newBook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(filename)
oSheet1 = newBook.worksheets("Sheet1")
oSheet1.Range("A1").Entirerow.Delete()


newBook.SaveAs(filename, FileFormat:=56)
appExcel.Workbooks.Close()
appExcel.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a syntax.
Go to control flow..
Pull in a data flow task.
Add a excel file source...add a conection manager
With excel sheet.
Open your connection manager and then check the box which says.
Column names In first row. That's it and add ur destination.

Comment: Can you tell me how to make a flat file source connect to an excel file?  The flat file source is for text files and can't read excel files, unless there's a trick I am not aware of.

Comment: I was experimenting with this and that option seems to tell the connection manager to look for headers or not.  If I uncheck that box, the column names don't show up.  It looks like this - http://imgur.com/FFqVKQD

If I leave the box checked, I am back to square one.

If I open the file and manually delete the header row, then save and close, when I have the box unchecked, I get what is in the picture I uploaded.  If I check the box, I get the results I want but I had to manually modify the file, which is what I'm trying to avoid

Comment: You can set OpenRowset property of Excel Data Source (Properties window, OpenRowset in Custom Properties section) to value similar to Sheet1$a2:m, where a is first column with your data, m is last column with data and 2 is the row with header just before data. Data should start in next row. So  you could set this, keeping in mind whether you want to check the column names in first row thing.